# android: uploading a picture to firebase after reducing the size to avoid out of memory error

Tags: android, firebase, bitmap, uri

I am trying to upload an image into Firebase but when the image has a big size it gives the OOM error. I've tried to use some libraries such as glide but I am not getting a reduced size.

Here is the code that changes a URI into a bitmap:

```
public byte[] getBytesFromUri(Uri uri, int quality) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    Bitmap bitmap=null;
    try {   
        bitmap=MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(),uri);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, stream);
    return stream.toByteArray();
}
```

And this is the upload to firebase section:

```
StorageReference file2path=mStorage.child("products_images").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child(nouveau_produit.getKey()).child("image_2");
file2path.putBytes(getBytesFromUri(resultUri2, 100)).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
        Uri second_Dwn_Url=taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
        image2=second_Dwn_Url.toString().trim();

        //images upload
        nouveau_produit.child("image_2").setValue(image2);
        nouveau_produit_category.child("image_2").setValue(image2);
    }
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(UploadActivity.this,"uploading of second image failed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

It seems the images I am uploading are very big.
This is the error I am getting when the app crashes:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: tk.a45developer.www.kukaguriro, PID: 13149
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:122)
    at tk.a45developer.www.kukaguriro.UploadActivity.getBytesFromUri(UploadActivity.java:1294)
    at tk.a45developer.www.kukaguriro.UploadActivity$10.onClick(UploadActivity.java:867)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4508)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18675)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5590)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1280)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1096)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: can you post your code or error?

Comment: right from the docs `Because putBytes() accepts a byte[], it requires your app to hold the entire contents of a file in memory at once. Consider using putStream() or putFile() to use less memory.`

Comment: @tyczj am uploading bytes so when i change to putStream() or putFile() i get an error because am uploading the image in form of bytes

Comment: Is your question _"How can i save big images in firebase storage?"_ or _"How can i reduce the size of an image?"_???

Comment: how can i reduce the size of an image(Uri) like from Megabytes to Kilobytes

Comment: @45davy You should edit your question to make your question more specific. (maybe take out the entire firebase bit because that is only generating an error, it has nothing to do with your actual question)

Answer (score 0):

thank you guys for your comments i just found a way to do it with the SiliCompressor library
here is my code where i changed the uri to bitmap using the sillycompressor library [sillycompressor github link](https://github.com/Tourenathan-G5organisation/SiliCompressor#silicompressor)

```
public byte[] getBytesFromUri(Uri uri, int quality) {

    ByteArrayOutputStream stream=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    Bitmap bitmap=null;
    try {
        bitmap = SiliCompressor.with(UploadActivity.this).getCompressBitmap(uri.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, stream);
    return stream.toByteArray();
}
```

Comment: Still a bad idea to make an intermediate bitmap. That bitmap just limits the size of the file that can be uploaded. If you just upload that file you will never get an oom and you can upload any file. Not only images.